# In airtable, combine multiple cells with different linked records into one cell with all linked records?

Tags: javascript, automation, airtable

In airtable, I have 2 cells, each containing 3 unique linked records. I want to combine the linked records in both cells into just one cell containing 6 unique linked records.

[image: combine unique linked records from multiple cells into one]

I have tried concatenate cell formula to do this, but it returns the text string of the record and not the linked record itself.

I don't want to manually add the 6 unique records to that cell, looking for ways to do it via automation/javascript/cell formulae.